# How to inject serverless parameter from environment variables?

Tags: serverless-framework, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to do a deployment using serverless to AWS, but I'm getting the following error.

> An error occurred: {ProjectName} - Invalid State Machine Definition:
>   'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: Expected value of type Integer at
>   /States/WaitForCampusM/Seconds' (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status
>   Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDefinition; Request ID:
>   1facfbb9-9570-456d-8c33-1a2dadaea5ff).

This was working fine when I was using a hard-coded value, but now I'm trying to use an environment variable so I can control the wait time differently between deployment and integration tests. This is all getting deployed through a BitBucket pipeline.

Here is the definition of my state in the step function:

```
WaitForCampusM:
    Type: Wait
    Seconds: ${env:CAMPUSM_WAIT_DELAY}
    Next: CampusMPull
```

This value is set within BitBucket deployment settings and I decided to `echo` out the value, so here is my pipeline

```
script:
    - npm install -g serverless
    - echo $CAMPUSM_WAIT_DELAY
    - sls deploy
```

This seems to log my value, which is a valid number (but I assume for some reason is being treated as a string?)

[image]

I've tried using `SecondsPath` in serverless too but unfortunately that didn't seem to work either. Can anyone see what else I might be missing?

Comment: You're doing everything right. Nothing is jumping out at me. I have 2 comments: #1 Let us know what the actual value is in CloudFormation. Go to your `.serverless` directory, look at the CF template, and paste the line with `Seconds`. Maybe there's an extra space in there or something? and #2 How are you declaring `$CAMPUSM_WAIT_DELAY`?

Comment: @solsglasses thanks. I decided after trying stuff to log an issue and it seems like it's a probable bug - https://github.com/horike37/serverless-step-functions/issues/280

Comment: Yep, I saw you created that GitHub Issue. Definitely a bug with `serverless-step-functions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are running into a problem which could be summarized as: *"Environment Variables are always strings"*. This is always handled in the code using, for example, `process.env` and forcing the value to be an Integer. Apparently the maintainers of `serverless-step-functions` have not done that, yet. I see you created a GitHub Issue to notify them of the problem, thanks!

In the meantime until they fix it, perhaps you should consider using another method to set different configuration data per stage/environment. Here's a code example that can work for you. Read here for more detailed explanation on a blog article I found: https://www.jeremydaly.com/how-to-manage-serverless-environment-variables-per-stage/

```
custom:
  CAMPUSM_WAIT_DELAY:
    stg: 43200
    prod: 43200
    other: 99999
```

```
WaitForCampusM:
    Type: Wait
    Seconds: ${self:custom.CAMPUSM_WAIT_DELAY.${self:provider.stage}, self:custom.CAMPUSM_WAIT_DELAY.other}
    Next: CampusMPull
```